# How to model the update-delay of observable variable in a model?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, mathematical-modeling, time-series, operations-research

**INFO:** *I have asked the same question last week at CS ([here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/161009/how-to-capture-the-update-delay-of-observable-variable-in-a-model)), but there is not even a single comment, so I am posting it here in hope someone might help with literature or approach.*

I have a problem that I am trying to model, but I am unable to capture one particularity of the system that seems to be crucial. I will try to give an abstract description first and then the toy model hoping that someone might have an idea or a reference suggestion.

Description: There is a system and I can observe one of its parameters $u$ - $u$ is nonnegative and bounded by some system constraints. There is an external parameter $v$ that I can control and I want it to be as close as possible in value to the observed parameter $u$. Unfortunately, there is a delay in observing the value of $u$ and updating the value of $v$: it is a time constant $D>0$.

Problem: I have historical data on observables $u$. Let us say that I have a vector of $u$ data points in some interval $[0,T]$. I would like to analyse this data and find the optimal vector of $v$-values that would minimize the L1 distance between $u$ and $v$ points. Unfortunately, I do not know how to write the condition that there is a delay $D$ involved: if $u_0$ and $v_0$ both start at $10$, and $u_1$ becomes $50$, then $v_1$ and up to $v_D$ are still $10$ and only $v_{D+1}$ is set to $50$.

A toy example: imagine you have a very expensive and limited memory system which is in every time instance given a new data to hold. The amount of data to hold is variable and the old data is simply overwritten and not needed anymore.

If in the next time instance you need to write more data than you have currently allocated, you write in what you can and put the remainder on the queue (you are penalised for using the queue) and issue an allocation request (and you get the requested memory after $D$ time instances have passed - for simplicity, the let the delay be the same in allocation and deallocation cases).

If in the next time instance you need to write less than you currently have, then you write everything in (you get penalised for having unused memory) and issue a deallocation request on the difference (and the memory is freed after $D$ time instances have passed).

I am trying to model this problem in order to try to find a $v$-vector (for a given $u$-vector) that minimizes the penalties.

Does anyone have any suggestion on references where I could look up these things further? Or and idea how to approach it? Thank you!

Comment: Is it that you want $v(t)$ to track $u(t)$ closely but you know that you don't really observe $u(t)$ but actually observe a delayed version $u(t-D)$?

Comment: Are you looking for a regression model (best fit to $u_t$ given data up to $u_{t-D}$)?

Comment: Both comments are related what I would like to do: 
Step 1) I would like first to get insights into what would be the optimal $v$ given a vector $u$ and the constraints of the system; 
Step 2) and then later to somehow to try to come up with a possible solution that would predict things on-the-fly (and possibly compare it with the optimal vector from the first step). 
Maybe those two are different problems that require different approaches.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza: Yes, precisely (at this step): $v(t)$ can only perform an immediate reaction to the value of $u(t-D)$, but the penalty/cost function looks at the difference of $v(t)$ and $u(t)$. But I am not sure how to capture this behaviour mathematically and write down an optimisation problem.

Comment: When I was trying to figure out what $v$ should look like I noticed that, if given no future data, $v$ stays constant during the first $D$ moments. So, I came to the idea that I should divide the problem on two subproblems: 
1) one on interval $[0, D]$ on which $v$ is constant: for this I would need to fit $u$ on $[0, D]$ with a constant function. 
2) and one on the interval $[D, T]$, where $v(t)$ is variable. For $t>D$, $v(t)$ is determined from $u$ data on $[0, t-D]$. 
But this is basically the same problem that I have encountered before splitting the time domain.

Comment: @prubin: That would be the natural next step in my analysis: given the values of $u_0, u_1, ..., u_{t-D}$, could we predict the value of $u_t$?
And then in the next step I would compare the vector of predicted values $\bar{v}$ with the "optimal" vector $\hat{v}$ from the previous step (the previous step gives "optimal" $v$-vector once we know all the $u$-values).

Comment: If you want to predict, you need a model of your process. What else is known about $u$ other than it is bounded and non-negative? If it can otherwise behave arbitrarily it will be more or less impossible to make any meaningful prediction.

Comment: @SampleTime: Unfortunately, it depends on the users and their processes. One might argue there is some seasonality depending on the time of the day and week, but I am afraid not much than that.

Comment: Then you will have to use the information of seasonality to construct a model of your process. It is not clear from your question what your optimization variables are, when you say "minimize the L1 distance between u and v". If you minimize over v, just set v=u, but that is most likely not what you want. So you will need some kind of model. Note that even a regression line (fitting a line through the past data of u to predict v) can be considered as a (very simple) model. Then your optimization variables would be the parameter of that line. But if that fits your task is very problem specific.

Comment: @SampleTime: The main problem is the following: how to model the delay $D$? If we look at the standard form of the optimization problem, where we minimise error in some norm, there is the norm of the difference $u-v$, where $u$ is given. Now, the question is from which space we pick $v$ - this is where I wanted to incorporate the delay. I do not know how. The regression and predictive behaviour is something that comes only later and at that stage modelling of $u$ would be important. I hope I am not missing something here with this approach...

Comment: You model the delay by creating a model of your process which you use to predict. Assume you have $u_0, u_1$ and you want $v_2$ such that $v_2=u_2$ but you don't know $u_2$ yet because of delay $D=1$ (one time step). With a model you compute $v_2$, a prediction of $u_2$. Then you tune your model such that $v_k\approx u_k$, e.g. you minimize $\sum_{k=0}^{N}|u_k-v_k|$ for your data set, while you perform the minimization *over your model parameters*. I don't get your last point about doing the regression and prediction "at a later stage". Your problem formulation is unclear.

Comment: @SampleTime: Ok, I think I get it now. Thank you for the explanation, I am still relatively new in all of this. It seems to me that the process modelling would require a bit more knowledge of control theory than what I know at the moment :D